# Locking in Java EE Application

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, concurrency, jpa-2.0

I am using Java EE 6 with JBOSS7 and JPA2 + Hibernate. For my client I provide a REST api.

My concern is how to efficiently ensure that no resources where modified concurrently. Should happen too often, but in case it happens I would like to ensure proper handling.

My approaches so far:

1. `Map<String, ReentrantLock>` to store the locks. (my ids are always
   `UUID`s) Locks are created on demand if missing in map. On this
   approach i like that concurrent access will be blocked and i can
   control how long the other thread tries to lock the resource.
2. Use JPA2 optimistic locking.

Which one would you recommend? Or is there an even better approach?

Comment: I suggest not inventing the wheel and satisfying your needs with JPA Locking system, after acquiring significant amount of knowledge on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. seems error-prone, plus it might not scale. I've never seen such
   design and would discourage it.
2. transactions with optimistic
   locking is a viable option. In this case, some transaction might
   fail and you will need to deal with errors and retry.
3. transactions with pessimistic locking is another viable option. It's
   like 1) but using the database to lock and order operations. AFAIK,
   JPA support pessimistic locking as well. Otherwise you can use
   `SELECT FOR UPDATE`(supported by most DBMS) to explicitely acquire row locks. Make sure you
   figure out a scheme were locks are acquired in consistent order, to
   avoid deadlocks.

The choice between 2-3 depends on the use case, e.g. if contention is expected to be high or not, or whether it is easy to retry a failed transaction.

Comment: Then i will go with the JPA locking. Thanks to both of you for your advice.